# Swift: Orientation Change with PushViewConteroller

Tags: swift, xcode, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to change the orientation of the View When it push from one ViewController to other view controller. Like when it push it should be change into the portrait to landscape.

I try to this code but not working properly.

In `ViewDidLoad`

```
struct AppUtility {
        static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
            if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
                delegate.orientationLock = orientation
            }
        }

        static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
            self.lockOrientation(orientation)
            UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }
```

In `ViewController`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight)
    }
```

But it does not change its Orientations.

Comment: as per my experience you should try this code in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`

Comment: no it's not work

Answer (score 0):

in app delegate

```
import UIKit
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var deviceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return deviceOrientation
    }
}
```

In UIViewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        appDelegate.deviceOrientation = .landscapeLeft
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have implemented same code and get same issue so i have add below code before calliing "lockOrientation" and resolve it.**

```
UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```